# Re-organizing a list in prolog

Tags: list, prolog

I am trying to write some Prolog code to take a list such as:

```
[[park, joe], [park, bob], [park, kate], [school, joe], [zoo, amy], [zoo, ted]].
```

and organizes the list into the form:

```
[[park,[joe, bob, kate]], [school,[joe]], [zoo,[amy, ted]]].
```

It can be assumed that all matching heads of each element (park = park, zoo = zoo) are directly next to each other in the list because the code I made to create the list sorts it in alphabetical order. I can't seem to figure out how to accomplish this and seem to get errors at every turn :(. Below is the code that I have so far in the last state that it ran without errors and I will try to explain what I was thinking.

```
merge([],[]).
merge([First|Rest], Z) :- 
merge(Rest, U),
[Meet1, Person1] = First,
( =(U, []) ->   % beginning case from recursion, U is empty
    Meet2 = [],
    Person2 = [];
    [[Meet2|Person2]|_] = U),
 ( =(Meet1, Meet2) -> % Case of matching heads, combine the tails
    print('Match '),
    append([First], U, Z); 
 print('No-match '), % otherwise, not matching
append([First], U, Z) ).
```

So what I was trying to do is use appends to add all of the changes to U and return it to the console with Z. such as,

```
( =(Meet1, Meet2) ->
  append(Person1, Person2, Combpersons),
  append([Meet1], [Combpersons], T),
  append(T, U, Z);
   ...no match code here..).
```

However my code keeps ending prematurely with a false when I try to change or add appends like this in the first block of code I put here. Even a change such as turning append([First], U, Z) into append([Meet1], U, Z) makes my code end with a false and I am not understanding why. Any help/hints on creating a solution would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that learning any language it's a process where low and high level issues *must* be interleaved. So far, you're learning the basic syntax. But why you use such unreadable constructs ? And of course, any programming language builds upon a set of *patterns*, usually covered by [libraries](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=group_pairs_by_key/2). Consider

```
l2p([A,B],A-B).

?- maplist(l2p,[[park, joe], [park, bob], [park, kate], [school, joe], [zoo, amy], [zoo, ted]], L),group_pairs_by_key(L,G).
L = [park-joe, park-bob, park-kate, school-joe, zoo-amy, zoo-ted],
G = [park-[joe, bob, kate], school-[joe], zoo-[amy, ted]].
```

Anyway, here is your code restructured:

```
merge([],[]).
merge([[Meet, Person]|Rest], Z) :- 
    merge(Rest, U),
    (   U = []
    ->  % beginning case from recursion, U is empty
        Z = [[Meet, [Person]]]
    ;   U = [[Meet, Persons] | Rest1]
    ->  % Case of matching heads, combine the tails
        Z = [[Meet, [Person | Persons]] | Rest1]
    ;   % otherwise, not matching
        Z = [[Meet, [Person]] | U]
    ).
```

Answer (score 1):

If you had your initial list as a list of pairs instead, you could use [library(pairs)](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=pairs), available in SWI-Prolog.

```
?- group_pairs_by_key([park-joe, park-bob, park-kate, school-joe, zoo-amy, zoo-ted], G).
G = [park-[joe, bob, kate], school-[joe], zoo-[amy, ted]].
```

Using the library gives you more than just this "reorganization". There is also [library(ugraphs)](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=ugraphs), which might be better suited, depending on what you are doing.

Comment: the same I'm writing about :)

Answer (score 0):

Your code fails, because you are trying to extract the place and the person before checking if there are any.

No use for `append` here, the reordering looks pretty complicated, but I did my best with the variable names. Furthermore you'll only need one `->`: If you hadn't found a tuple with the same first coordinate, you'll want a to start a new, it doesn't matter if there was none before.

```
merge([],[]).
merge([[Place,Person]|Rest], [[Place,Group]|OtherGroups]) :- 
    merge(Rest, U),
    (U = [[Place,Others]|OtherGroups] ->
     Group = [Person|Others];
     [OtherGroups,Group] = [U, [Person]]).
```

*Edit:* I changed the solution for readablity reasons.